# What is this sound called?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, word-choice, punctuation, sounds

So, I know there is a word for this sound, but it's driving me nuts. For some reason I'm remembering troleling?

Basically, I'm asking what is the sound when someone goes like, "Tra la la dee dah!". Or maybe if it's an Indian war cry? You know, the whole, "whoo whoo whoo whoo whoo!" or, "Lah Lah Lah Lah Lah!" sound made with our tongues jumping behind our top/front teeth.

(Side note, how is my punctuation?)

Comment: Singing "Tra la la" is rather different from an "Indian war cry". One of the definitions of _troll_ (as a verb) is _sing (something) in a happy and carefree way - "he trolled a note or two"_ - but I think this is likely to be misunderstood because of the other meanings of the word.

Comment: Do you mean a trilling sound? Or a whooping sound?

Comment: Do you mean _yodelling_?

Comment: If what you're thinking of is ***ululating***, you should note that Anglophones rarely use that word *because Anglophones rarely ululate*. Culturally speaking it's far more common among Arabs and Indians than among Brits, Americans, Canadians, Australians, etc. We might ***whoop***, but we don't normally do ululating or yodelling.

Comment: The words you're using to describe that sound are still about general with lots of possible very different sounds. A youtube video of someone doing what you're talking about would help immensely

Comment: @FumbleFingers -  Ululating went on in Kenyan villages, according to my uncle, who was a doctor there in the 1950s.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I'm not exactly sure *why* ululating is avoided by native Anglophones, but my best guess would probably be considered potentially offensive anyway. WASP Americans would avoid it because their great-great-grandfathers would have severely chastised their great-grandfathers as children if they were caught imitating "primitive" native war-cries when playing "Cowboys and Indians". And it'd be much the same with the Brits abroad running the Raj in (actual) India. Plus it's reminiscent of Tarzan's whooping through the African jungle - again, presented as "primitive".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - in the 1950s in England, "Cowboys and Indians" was a thing. My mother taught me to make an 'Indian war cry' by making a prolonged 'Waaahh' sound with my mouth, at the same time rapidly covering and uncovering my mouth with my hand. I understand that true ululation involves only the tongue and uvula. You will find it in parts of Europe (e.g. Cyprus) and among Mizrahi Jews, including American ones. I have to say that in my childhood games it was no shame to 'be an Indian'.

Comment: I don't actually know words to distinguish "ululating" with "oscillating **tongue**" from Tarzan's jungle cry (with "oscillating **larynx / throat**"), but they're both different to "yodelling". And to be honest - as a native Anglophone, the first example of yodelling that comes to mind is in [The Sound of Music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmmOJx_Hxto). Where it's essentially an Alpine / Austrian thing, not really "British". But your observation about your childhood context simply confirms my point. It's primarily for children and "foreigners", not grown-up native Anglophones.

Answer (score 2):

**troll** (v.)

> To **troll** a song, to roll it out with rise and fall of the voice
> [probably the equivalent of Swiss *tralallen*,  to sound notes without
> words—from a representation of the notes by the syllables
> *tra-la-la*]. [*United Editors Encyclopedia and Dictionary*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/United_Editors_Encyclopedia_and_Dictiona/LIZIAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=troll%20tra%20la%20la&pg=PP536&printsec=frontcover) (1907)

> To ***troll*** or ***trowl*** a song may be to roll it out with rise and fall
> of voice, but it is more probably the equivalent of G. *trallen,
> trallern, trällern,* Swiss *trallen, tralallen, trallallen,* to sing
> a tune, to sound notes without words; from a representation of the
> notes by the syllables *tra-la-la*. [*Dictionary of English Etymology*
> Vol. 3](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dictionary_of_English_Etymology/y3IPAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=troll%20tra%20la%20la&pg=PA421&printsec=frontcover) (1865)

> (Used with object)
> To sing or utter in a full, rolling voice.
>
> (Used without object)
> To sing with a full, rolling voice; give forth full, rolling tones.
> To be uttered or sounded in such tones. [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/troll)

---

> When success had finally crowned his efforts, a sudden impulse of
> boyish exuberance caused him to **troll out** an old Tyrolese Alpine
> song, "Tra, la, la, la, la, la, la, tra, la la, tra, la la!" with a
> peculiar flute-like execution. [Alica McAlilly; *Terra Cotta*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Terra_Cotta/EPJEAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=troll%20tra%20la%20la&pg=PA93&printsec=frontcover). (1903)

> "...How am I ever to speak to her to-day, if I fill my head with such
> sickly rubbish? Tra-la-la-la-lira! A fine day for a walk. I must go
> early and get to business. Somehow or other the thing must be managed.
> Tra-la-la-la-la."
> Cheerfully **trolling** a Tyrolean scrap, he set to
> work on his breakfast... [Lucy B. Walford; *Mr. Smith*, Vol. 2](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mr_Smith/oK8xAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=trolling%20tra%20la&pg=PA101&printsec=frontcover) (1876)

> Sometimes he twirled a great quarterstaff which he held in his hands,
> and again he would start whistling, or begin **trolling** a song at
> the top of a loud voice. [Henry Gilbert; *Robin Hood*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Robin_Hood/kizxmUrxXJUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=trolling%20a%20song&pg=PA56&printsec=frontcover)

> Think I perchance to sing or **troll** a tune
> For medicine against sleep, the music soon [Aeschylus; *Agamemnon*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Agamemnon/PvkgEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22troll%20a%20tune%22&pg=PT5&printsec=frontcover)

> The saloons (there are five) no longer feature a "stink of stale beer
> and thick voices bellowing pidgin German or **trolling out** dirty
> songs—vice gone feeble and unenterprising." [*Life*, June 23, 1947](https://books.google.com/books?id=N0gEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA104&dq=trolling%20a%20song&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqrJSl5oH0AhV8RzABHR8tBl4Q6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=trolling%20a%20song&f=false)

Comment: Just to note: though this is IMO the most targeted answer, and I see it in major dictionaries without being noted as archaic, I doubt that it's common enough in modern usage (outside of the line "Troll the ancient Yuletide carol") for it to be readily recognized.

Comment: I agree. If you use _troll_ in this sense, you are likely to be misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Try *ululate* which Merriam-Webster (online) defines as an intransitive verb meaning

> to utter a loud, usually protracted, high-pitched, rhythmical sound
> especially as an expression of sorrow, joy, celebration, or reverence

offering the sample usages

> eight singers took to the aisle, dancing with ferocious energy as the
> chorus sang, ululated and clapped in an exuberant, multisensory ode to
> joy.

> As soon as he said our mother's name, my
> sisters began to wail: keening, ululating cries, the Greek expression
> of sorrow for the dead.

From *ululate* we can derive the noun *ululation*, the *-ing* form of the verb *ululating*, etc.

I expect other reputable dictionaries offer much the same definition.